# Replacing in pandas dataframe (word frequency) a word after defining rules in a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataset

```
Word    Frequency
0   :   79
1   ,   60
2   cosa    26
3   e   26
4   a   25
... ... ...
526 rinviato    1
527 sconto  1
528 sui 1
529 libri   1
529 libro   1
530 casa    1
```

I would like to replace there `libri` with `libro`. I tried as follows:

```
my_dictionary={'libri':'libro'}
df.Word=df.Word.replace(my_dictionary)
```

but when I print df I do not see any changes

```
   Word Frequency
    0   :   79
    1   ,   60
    2   cosa    26
    3   e   26
    4   a   25
    ... ... ...
    526 rinviato    1
    527 sconto  1
    528 sui 1
    529 libri   1
    529 libro   1
    530 casa    1
```

Do you know the reason why?

Code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(word_dist.most_common(1000),
                    columns=['Word', 'Frequency'])


df.Word = df['Word'].replace(my_dictionary, regex=True)
```

where my_dictionary is defined as follows: `my_dictionary={'libri': 'libro', 'sui':'suo'}` and so on

Comment: `my_dictionary={'libri'='libro'}` This causes an error.

Comment: sorry it was with : not with =

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regex=True:

```
my_dictionary={'libri':'libro'}
df.Word= df['Word'].replace(my_dictionary, regex=True)
```

Comment: I updated the answer can you try this to see if it resolves your problem?

Comment: Do you really assign it to the same column? I don't see any reason that it doesn't work

Comment: I tried to replicate the question and run, and it worked

Comment: Can I see a screenshot of your code or the data to check it

Comment: there  was a comma after } . This was causing the wrong replacement. Thanks a lot MhDG7 :)